# GPIO buttons problems in C++

Tags: c++, embedded, embedded-linux, interrupt, gpio

I have a particular problem, I am working in an application in c++ on linux. This is going to be an embedded application in a board. I have a while(true) because should be working permanent, my problem is that I have buttons connected to my board, but this is  not active until some variable is change. here is the code:

```
while (true){

//doing stuffs

if(Control ){



            int ready = poll(pfd, 7, timeout);
            gpio_set_value(ledActual,1);

            if (pfd[0].revents & POLLPRI) {

                    cout<<"FRONT"<<endl;
                    valueToSend=3;//Front
                    if(ledActual!=0)//Apagamos el Led que esta encendido
                            gpio_set_value(ledActual,0);

                    actualEthValue = receivedEthValue;

                //  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &videoFrontConfiguration, NULL);

                //  if(trueControl)
                        //Enviar(valueToSend);//We send Front value

                    len = read(pfd[0].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
                    gpio_set_value(gpio8,1);//Encendemos el Led
                    ledActual=gpio8;

            }

            if (pfd[1].revents & POLLPRI) {

                cout<<"LEFT"<<endl;
                    valueToSend=4;//Left
                    if(ledActual!=0)//Apagamos el Led que esta encendido
                            gpio_set_value(ledActual,0);

                    actualEthValue = receivedEthValue;

                //  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &videoLeftConfiguration, NULL);

                //  if(trueControl)
                        //Enviar(valueToSend);//We send Left value

                    len = read(pfd[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
                    gpio_set_value(gpio9,1);//Encendemos el Led
                    ledActual=gpio9;

            }

            if (pfd[2].revents & POLLPRI) {

                    cout<<"RIGHT"<<endl;
                    valueToSend=5;//Right
                    if(ledActual!=0)//Apagamos el Led que esta encendido
                            gpio_set_value(ledActual,0);

                    actualEthValue = receivedEthValue;

                //  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &videoRightConfiguration, NULL);
                //  if(trueControl)
                        //Enviar(valueToSend);//We send Right value

                    len = read(pfd[2].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
                    gpio_set_value(gpio10,1);//Encendemos el Led
                    ledActual=gpio10;

            }
}
}
```

So my problem is that when the boolean is change and enter into the "buttons function" also it seem that the button are pushed, so I can see the "cout" in the console like this:

FRONT
LEFT
RIGHT

And like I have to throw the threads the all of three threads are throwing at the same time then I got a segmentation fault.

So why it seem that someone push the buttons when the "Control" change. All the buttons are setted like a falling because the board put all as "high level".

Thank you so much I hope someone cans see the solution

Adding:

I have defined the "pdf vector" like this:

```
                    pfd[0].fd = gpio_fd;
                    pfd[0].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[0].revents = 0;

                    pfd[1].fd = gpio_fd2;
                    pfd[1].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[1].revents = 0;

                    pfd[2].fd = gpio_fd3;
                    pfd[2].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[2].revents = 0;


                    pfd[3].fd = gpio_fd4;
                    pfd[3].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[3].revents = 0;


                    pfd[4].fd = gpio_fd5;
                    pfd[4].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[4].revents = 0;


                    pfd[5].fd = gpio_fd6;
                    pfd[5].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[5].revents = 0;


                    pfd[6].fd = gpio_fd7;
                    pfd[6].events = POLLPRI;
                    pfd[6].revents = 0;
```

I defined the gpio's like this:
                //FRONT
                gpio_export(gpio);
                gpio_set_dir(gpio, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
                gpio_set_edge(gpio, "falling");
                gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open(gpio);

```
        //LEFT
        gpio_export(gpio2);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio2, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio2, "falling");
        gpio_fd2 = gpio_fd_open(gpio2);

        //REAR
        gpio_export(gpio3);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio3, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio3, "falling");
        gpio_fd3 = gpio_fd_open(gpio3);

        //RIGHT
        gpio_export(gpio4);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio4, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio4, "falling");
        gpio_fd4 = gpio_fd_open(gpio4);

        //TOP
        gpio_export(gpio5);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio5, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio5, "falling");
        gpio_fd5 = gpio_fd_open(gpio5);


        //CYCLE
        gpio_export(gpio6);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio6, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio6, "falling");
        gpio_fd6 = gpio_fd_open(gpio6);

        //QUAD
        gpio_export(gpio7);
        gpio_set_dir(gpio7, 0);//If is 1 = out || 0 = in
        gpio_set_edge(gpio7, "falling");
        gpio_fd7 = gpio_fd_open(gpio7);
```

Because my board set every GPIO like high level

Comment: Have you checked that ready>0 before analyszing the pollfd content ?

Comment: Hi Christophe thank you for your answer, I just checked and yes, ready=7, so for that the thread is going to enter always. How can I solved this?

Comment: Anyways the ready value should be >0 and !=0, what I do not undestand is why enter in the buttons, so like the buttons was pushed when is not